# Selenium DevToolsProtocol setUserAgentOverride

Tags: selenium, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to change "accept-language" header for selenium bot. As i find out there are 2 opportunities to do this: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setUserAgentOverride and https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setUserAgentOverride . The question is what the difference between this methods. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setUserAgentOverride also has acceptLanguage. As far as I can tell, both APIs are identical. What's interesting is the optional parameter, userAgentMetadata, in Network.setUserAgentOverride references the Emulation.UserAgentMetadata as it's type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically trying to change the *`accept-language`* header then you have to use [*Emulation.setUserAgentOverride*](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setUserAgentOverride).

```
Emulation.setUserAgentOverride: Allows overriding user agent with the given string.

PARAMETERS
    userAgent(string): User agent to use.
    acceptLanguage(string): Browser langugage to emulate.
    platform(string): The platform navigator.platform should return.
```